# shinyApp in flexdashboard show only in half screen

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

so yesterday my app was working fine, i use shinyApp in flexdashboard and there was no problem with the screen. But when i update the last package of shiny from rstudio, now when i launch my app the shiny app is only on half screen. I changed nothing on my script.

Please can someone help me ?

Before

[image]

After update shiny:

[image]

Example of script in flexdashoard

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste your code instead of a screenshot. Also having a version of your data (could be faked) is useful in order to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried so many options,  however this structure worked for me... my problem only happened when I knitr or published, this is why I think the option added outside the server and UI is what worked.

```
---
title: "Change Up Ur Analytics"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      vertical_layout: scroll
      orientation: rows
---
```

```
             <data and libraries here >
```

```
shinyApp(ui= 

               < ui here inputs, outputs formats .. I use combinations of 
                  bs4Dash, fluidPage, fluidRows, css, html  and have sometimes used
                   the new bootstrap4  > 

,  

server = function(input, output) {


          < plot creation  and filters and more reactive  here > 


  }  ,options = list(height = 700)
)
```

hope this helps....Fiona